# Vuex logic with routes and refresh

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I'm working on a project with Vue, Vuex and Vue-Router, but I'm having a big problem wrapping my head around the flow of async actions and components.

In my main component I dispatch an action to fetch a list of projects with ajax.

My list component receives the array of projects from this getter:

```
allProjects: state => state.projects
```

This works great since the default state is an empty array. My problem is when I want to go to route `project/:id`, if the projects are already loaded it works with this code:

```
computed: {
    project () {
        return this.$store.state.fram.projects.find(item => item.id === this.id);
    }
}
```

But if I refresh the page while at route `project/4` nothing works. I understand it's because the action fetching all projects is not finished yet. But I was hoping Vue(X) would realise it when the array is populated and update the computed project variable. Is this wrong? What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `getters` in your `store` that return the state and use `mapGetters` in your component. while destructuring the desired getters.

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
         'your_getter'
       ]),
}
```

API: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Georgi, shift the logic from the computed property to a store getter:

***store.js***

```
const getters = {
  project: state => {
    return id => {  // note this passes the id from the component

      return state.fram && state.fram.projects   // in case async not done yet
        ? state.fram.projects.find(item => item.id === id)
        : null

    }
  }
}
```

***myComponent.vue***

```
computed: {
  project () {
    return this.$store.getters.project(this.id) 
  }
}
```

Not too sure about the use of **mapGetters** in this context though.